# SQLite & Perl Query Issue with Email Address

Tags: perl, sqlite, email

I'm trying to query an SQLite3 database (in preparation for building a perl based webpage with authentication for a university assignment). The problem I have is that the database is returning a null result when trying to query by the email address which is also the username for the purpose of this database.

The query looks as follows:

```
my $sql = "SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE email_address = 'xxxxx@xxxxx.xxxxx.edu.au'";
my $sth = $dbh->prepare( $sql ) or die( "Can't prepare: " . $dbh->errstr() );
$sth->execute() or die( "Can't execute: " . $sth->errstr() );

my @row;
while( @row = $sth->fetchrow_array() )
{
    print join( q/, /, @row ), "\n";
}
```

This prints out a null result. Yet if I were to query via the first_name or last_name fields on the database I'm able to get the data to print out.

The email address is in the following format: xxx@xxx.xxx.edu.au

The database structure is as follows:

```
accounts(
email_address VARCHAR(50) PRIMARY KEY,
last_name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
first_name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
password VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
pass_salt VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
account_balance DOUBLE
);
```

Any advice anyone can offer would be much apreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You correctly identified what the problem is, but your solution is less than optimal. Instead of escaping the input manually in your code, you should be using [placeholders](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#Placeholders-and-Bind-Values). DBI makes this very comfortable.

That's done putting `?` without quotes into your SQL, and then passing the arguments to `execute`. DBI will handle all the escaping of characters that carry a meaning in SQL, thus rendering SQL injection impossible. This was not a problem in this case, but it's a nice bonus.

```
my $email = 'xxxxx@xxxxx.xxxxx.edu.au';
my $sql = "SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE email_address = ?";
my $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql) or die "Can't prepare: " . $dbh->errstr;
$sth->execute($email) or die "Can't execute: " . $sth->errstr;

my @row;
while ( @row = $sth->fetchrow_array ) {
    print join( q/, /, @row ), "\n";
}
```

Of course, you could have simply used single quotes `'` for the whole SQL as well since you're not doing any variable interpolation anyway. However, you should **always use placeholders**.

---

It looks like you are trying to produce a CSV file. Take a look at [Text::CSV](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::CSV), it will make your life easier.

Answer (score 1):

You are right about perl interpolating arrays into your string, but you should also have seen a message that warned you of that

```
Possible unintended interpolation of @xxxxx in string
```

It's also much better to use *placeholders* in your SQL string and pass the real data in your call to `execute`. It has the advantage that you need only `prepare` your SQL statement once, but `execute` it multiple times with different values for the email address. It also handles any necessary quoting of the values for you

I suggest your code should look like this

```
my $account_by_email = $dbh->prepare('SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE email_address = ?');

$account_by_email->execute('xxxxx@xxxxx.xxxxx.edu.au');

while ( my @row = $account_by_email->fetchrow_array ) {
    print join( ', ', @row ), "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok I'm blind, everyone ignore me. Forgetting that @ dictates an array in perl I didn't think about escaping the @ symbol in the email address. So looks like a minor bit of regex will be needed for email addresses to make sure queries can be put through.

Simple solution:

```
my $sql = "SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE email_address = 'xxxxx\@xxxxx.xxxxx.edu.au'";
                                                              ^ inserted escape char!
```

Comment: A better way would be to use single-quotes instead of double-quotes. Since your string already contains single quotes around the email address, you will need to use `q//` to supply an alternative delimiter. `q{SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE email_address = 'xxxxx@xxxxx.xxxxx.edu.au'}` will work fine